# How to use function and HTML together in functions.php in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

All I have an issue. Please help I am fresher I need a guide.

I have to use the function to get custom field value and need to set that value in my anchor link. but that print outside the link

```
// add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'technical_specification_pdf_url', 32 );
function technical_specification_pdf_url (){
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'wc-attibute-class' );
    if ( !empty($terms)) {
            $term = array_pop($terms);
                    $text= get_field('technical_specification_pdf', $term);
                    if (!empty($text)) {
                    echo $text;
                    }
    }
}


//  technical specification
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'technical_specification_button', 30 );

function technical_specification_button() {
  global $product;
  echo '<a href=".'technical_specification_pdf_url()'.">technical specification</a>';
}
```

I need a button in Woocommerce single page where I can display the brochure link.
My function is working fine just the value doesn't add inside the href tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In function `technical_specification_pdf_url`, you must return the `$text` to append it in function `technical_specification_pdf_url`.

**Step 1:** Update `echo $text;` to `return $text;`.

**Step 2:** Add `return null;` to function `technical_specification_pdf_url` to let you know that product doesn't exists `technical_specification_pdf_url` field.

**Step 3:** Add `if ($url)` to check the exists condition, with `$url = technical_specification_pdf_url();`. Because you are doing it on all products, so you should ignore the other products.

```
// add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'technical_specification_pdf_url', 32 );
function technical_specification_pdf_url (){
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'wc-attibute-class' );
    if ( !empty($terms)) {
            $term = array_pop($terms);
                    $text= get_field('technical_specification_pdf', $term);
                    if (!empty($text)) {
                       return $text;   // Fix here
                    }
    }

    // return null if doesn't exists technical_specification_pdf field
    return null;
}


//  technical specification
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'technical_specification_button', 30 );

function technical_specification_button() {
  $url = technical_specification_pdf_url();
  // Add check URL here, if not exists, do nothing
  if ($url) {
    global $product;
    echo "<a href=". $url .">technical specification</a>";
  }
}
```

Comment: show Error in

syntax error, unexpected 'technical_specification_pdf_ur' (T_STRING), expecting ';' or ','

Comment: @PalashMandal I updated function `technical_specification_button()`. Try it again. If it's still errors, could you show me which line?